# Print words in string in reverse order C

Tags: c, user-input

I take user input using fgets() and store it into a temp array. I then concatenate that to a main array called userInput so that the user can enter multiple lines.

Let's say the user enters the following:

```
This is a sentence
This is a new line
```

I need it to print each line in the order they were entered but reverse the order of words like below:

```
sentence a is This
line new a is This
```

I have the current approach but I get this:

```
line
new a is sentence
This a is This
```

Below is my code where I call `reversePrint()` with a string to reverse:

```
void printToSpace(const char *str) {
  do {
    putc(*str, stdout);
  } while(*str++ != ' ');
}

void reversePrint(const char *str) {
  const char *p = strchr(str, ' ');
  if (p == NULL) {
    printf("%s", str);
  }
  else {
    reversePrint(p + 1);
    printToSpace(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems you're almost there - you just need to control the `"\n"` character that's attached to the word you're printing... try removing the tokens (the space or new line) and printing them separately from the words.

Comment: Are you able to resolve the problem? Your program works fine as is except for one space.

Comment: Note that `fgets` leaves the newline character on the end of the buffer. That may or may not be what you want, depending on how you intend to keep track of lines in the main array.  Assuming that you intended to have newlines in the main array, you can use `strpbrk(str, " \n")` instead of `strchr(str, ' ')` to search for the next space or newline. And the `printToSpace` function should actually print to the next space or newline.

Comment: Just because `(p == NULL)` doesn't mean there isn't a string to reverse. What about the input `"thisWord"`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reversePrint(const char *str)
{
    if (str)
    {
        reversePrint(strtok (NULL, " \t\n\r"));
        printf("%s ", str);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "This is a sentence";
    reversePrint(strtok(string, " \t\n\r"));
    return 0;
}
```

It seems so clear and simple that I suspect if `strtok()` is born for requirements like this.

Comment: as pointed to in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html), `strtok` will modify the original string (it's destructive)... Since a lot of effort was taken to keep the original string intact, it might be an issue. Also, `strtok` on Linux **"cannot be used on constant strings"**, so your example isn't portable... also, it isn't thread safe (but that's really a non-issue for this example, but it's good to know).

Comment: @Myst Thanks for pointing out these. Never know these before.

Answer (score 1):

Here are just a few thoughts...

1. I feel that using `fgets` will provide you with an undesired new-line marker. Hence, you need to handle the `"\r\n"` in the reverse printing function.
2. I feel that the reverse printing is easier to perform in a single function, although I loved the recursive approach, so I'll use it here.

   I should point out that I wouldn't use a recursive function if this was a production application, as we'll be wasting resources and bloating the stack for no good reason.

   On a non-recursive approach I would probably use the `%.*s` format, instead of printing each char separately.

I think your code would work if you only changed `printToSpace` so that it manages the `\n` contingency - but I felt like re-writinfg the function. Try this in your solution:

```
void printToSpace(const char *str) {
  do {
    putc(*str, stdout);
  } while(*str && *str != '\n' && *str != '\r' && *str++ != ' ');
}
```

Here's my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_rev(char* str);

// collects two strings and send them to the `print_rev` function
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  char str_array[2][255];
  // Get string 1
  printf("Enter the first string (up to 255 characters):\n");
  fgets(str_array[0], 255, stdin);
  printf("Please enter the second string (up to 255 characters):\n");
  fgets(str_array[1], 255, stdin);
  printf("You entered:\n1. %s2. %s", str_array[0], str_array[1]);
  printf("\nString 1 reversed: ");
  print_rev(str_array[0]);
  printf("\nString 2 reversed: ");
  print_rev(str_array[1]);
  printf("\n");
}

// prints a string in reverse order.
void print_rev(char* str) {
  // find the first occurrence of the ` ` (space)
  char* p = strchr(str, ' ');
  // if a space exists...
  if (p) {
    // call `print_rev` for whatever's after the space.
    print_rev(p + 1);
    // print a space
    putc(' ', stdout);
  }
  // print every character until an EOL, space or NULL is encountered
  while (*str && *str != ' ' && *str != '\n' && *str != '\r')
    putc(*(str++), stdout);
}
```

Comment: Nice catch @Michi - I missed a `'\'` when comparing against the `'\r'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 100000

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN], temp[MAX_LEN];
    printf("Enter the Sentence to print reverse : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &str);
    int i, left, right, length = strlen(str);
    left = 0;
    right = length - 1;

    printf("%d \n", length);

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        temp[i] = str[right];
        right--;
    }

     printf("%s",temp);

     return 0;
}
```